# Using WordPress admin_notices in a OOP plugin

Tags: php, oop, wordpress

I've registered a new admin page in WordPress where I display out output HTML and format and validate some input and save to the DB. All works great. What isn't really working is using the admin_notices hook to display any error / update messages. I'me guessing I can't call that hook from within the add_menu_page function? If so how are you suppose to handle errors on custom pages in OOP plugins?

I've included a very stripped down version of the code below.

```
class Fitems_Admin {

    public $admin_notices = array();

    public function __construct(){
        // Register Menus
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'register_menus' ) );
    }

    public function register_menus(){
        add_menu_page( 'fItems', 'fItems', 'administrator', 'fItems', array( $this, 'items' ) );
    }

    public function items(){
        // do stuff, validate input & register any errors, example below
        $this->admin_notices['updated'][] = __( 'item(s) successfully deleted.', 'fItems' );
        // Register errors
        add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this , 'display_admin_notices' ) );
        // display output;
        echo $output;
    }

    // Just formats and echos any errors in the $this->admin_notices array();
    public function display_admin_notices( $return = FALSE ){
        if( ! empty( $this->admin_notices ) ){
            // Remove an empty and then sort
            array_filter( $this->admin_notices );
            ksort( $this->admin_notices );
            $output = '';
            foreach( $this->admin_notices as $key => $value ){
                // Probably an array but best to check
                if( is_array( $value ) ){
                   foreach( $value as $v ){
                       $output .= '<div class="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '"><p>' . esc_html( $v ) . '</p></div>';
                   }
                } else {
                    $output .= '<div class="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '"><p>' . esc_html( $value ) . '</p></div>';
                }
            }
            if( $return ){
                return $output;
            } else {
                echo $output;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try it may works!

store your all notices in a variable `$error_notices`

`$error_notices =   $this->admin_notices['updated'][] = __( 'item(s) successfully deleted.', 'fItems' );`


`function my_admin_notice() {`
`global $error_notices;`
`echo $error_notices;`

`}`

`add_action( 'admin_notices', $this->my_admin_notice );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Admin Notices are not used for this and the hook don't work at the point where you're putting it. And to trigger it selectively, we use `get_option` or `get_user_meta`.

For this kind of *notice*, we use admin classes:

```
if( $success )
    echo '<div class="updated"><p>class .updated with paragraph</p></div>';

if( $error )
    echo '<div class="error"><p>class .error with paragraph</p></div>';
```

Here's a helper plugin to style our admin screens: [WordPress Admin Styles](http://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style).

Or, use the whole [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), which has a function [`add_settings_error()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_error) to display notices, despite the name, it is used to display `update` and `error` messages.

Comment: Humm, ok so I was doing it correctly the first time. I guess you can go a little integration mad trying to use as many WordPress built in functions as possible!! Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. It's not actually a settings page though, (or uses any of the settings API), it's  custom form. The question is should add_settings_error() be used only in conjunction with the settings API or should it be used as a general error/notification function. I'm thinking the former?

Comment: We can only that function if using the API. . . . . And we can use the API freely in any of our custom plugin or theme pages. [This example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26612) does not compile for some misconfigurations, but that's the idea.

Comment: How do you determine after the redirect if it is a success or error?